# javafx tableview does not show content

Tags: java, javafx

I recently started programming with JavaFx. I have the following Problem:
I am writing a controller class, in which I hava a Table with orders, but the content can only be set in the initialize method.

The List with orders should be set in the orderTable with the method **setorderList**.    The problem is that the Orders are not shown in the TableView.
I have already tried to trigger an update of the TableView by removing the items of the Table and filling them up again.

For test purposes i created the orderList with a test-order in the initialize() method and set them to the table with **orderTable.setItems(orderList)**. When i did this it worked perfectly.
So the order from the initialize method (with number 23) is shown in the Table but the List thats set in **setOrderList** is not.
This confuses me, because it seems like the **orderTable.setItems(orderList)** Statement only works in the initialize() method.
Here is my code:

```
public class OrderOverviewController implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private TableView<Order> orderTable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Order,Integer> orderNumberColumn;

    private ObservableList<Order> orderList;

    private OrderDao orderDao;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        orderNumberColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("orderId"));

        orderList=FXCollections.observableArrayList();  
                      //ordernumber and Current user
        orderList.add(new Order(23,null));
        orderTable.setItems(orderList);

    }

    public void setOrderList(ObservableList<Order> orderList) {

        orderTable.setItems(orderList);
    }

}
```

This is the start method of the main class where i setup the scenes for my application. First the LoginN.fxml gets loaded, and the mainScene is only set up. After this the LoginManager gets created.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

    this.stage=primaryStage;
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view /LoginN.fxml"));
    loginScene=new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(loginScene);
    primaryStage.show();

    root=null;

    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/Main.fxml"));

    mainScene=new Scene(root);
    new LoginManager(this);
}
```

So here is my LoginManager which has an static instance of itself, so i can access it easier.
The method **setLoggedInUser** sets the user after the login procedure as you can see in the next code sample which contains the method login.
Here i get all orders of the user, with which i call then the **setOrderMethod** of the controller where my Problem with the table is.

```
public class LoginManager {

private static LoginManager loginManager;
private Main main;
private User loggedInUser;
private OrderDao orderDao;

private MainController mainController;
private OrderOverviewController ooc;

public LoginManager(Main main){
    loginManager=this;
    this.main=main;

}

public static LoginManager getInstance(){
    return loginManager;
}

public void setMainView(){

    main.setMainView();

}


public void setLoggedInUser(User loggedInUser) {

        this.loggedInUser = loggedInUser;

        //load OrderViewController to set Previous orders
        try {

            URL location=getClass().getResource("/view/Orders.fxml");
            FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(location);
            loader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
            Parent root=(Parent)loader.load(location.openStream());


            orderDao=new OrderDao();
            ooc=loader.getController();
            ooc.setOrderList(orderDao.getOrdersOfUser(loggedInUser));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

}

Here is the login method of the LoginController which gets triggered when the loginButton is pressed:

```
    public void login() throws Exception{

    userName=usernameField.getText();
    password=AESCrypt.encrypt(passwordField.getText());

    if(userdao.isUserValid(userName, password))
    {
        LoginManager.getInstance().setMainView();
        LoginManager.getInstance().setLoggedInUser(userdao.getUserByName(userName));
    }

    else
        errorLabel.setText("Login failed!");

}
```

If the userData was valid the mainScene gets set up with the LoginManager and the logged in user is set.

This is how i included the Orders.fxml (The view of the OrderOverviewController) in a Tab in the Main view:

```
  <fx:define>
     <fx:include source="Orders.fxml" fx:id="orderOverviewContent"/>
  </fx:define>

  <Tab content="$orderOverviewContent" text="Order Overview" />
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where do you want to call the `setOrderList()` from?

Comment: I call it from a class called LoginManager. Thats the class which holds the Informations of the logged in user.

Comment: Does `LoginManager` loads the FXML for which, `OrderOverviewController` is the controller?

Comment: No, i have another fxml for the login with a loginController.
In this LoginController the fxml for the OrderOverviewController is loaded.

Comment: Can you show the code where you load the FXML, and the code where you call the `setOrderList(...)` method? How are you passing the controller from the place where the fxml is loaded to the `LoginManager`?

Comment: You need to fetch the controller from the FXMLLoader and then somehow access the controller from the `LoginManager`. **And use this instance of the controller** to call `setOrderList()`.

Comment: @James_D i added now all methods that happen before the call of setOrderList().

Comment: @ItachiUchiha yes, i fetched the controller of my orders.fxml in the method setLoggedInUser()

Comment: This seems a bit convoluted, but I think I follow the order of method calls. Presumably in the setLoggedInUser method you do something with root to display it in the UI that you haven't shown? Can you verify that the setOrderList(...) method is being called via a System.out.println(...)? And to confirm, there is only one instance of OrderOverviewController that is created, right? If it helps, I created a [barebones example](https://github.com/james-d/AppWithLogin) of how I usually set up login-based apps.

Comment: If you are loading the FXML solely to get an instance of the controller, then you are getting a different instance from the one that is connected to the UI that is actually shown. A controller instance is created each time you call `load(...)` on the `FXMLLoader`. You need to get the controller when you load the FXML *and display it* and pass a reference to that controller to the place you need it. To see what I mean, add a constructor to the controller that just does a `System.out.println("Creating controller");`: you will see that it is called more than once.

Comment: @James_D yes i know, i am sorry but it's kind of my first bigger application i tried with fx.
Everything works, also the setOrderList(...) method is called. There are also the right orders in it. I have already checked that via System.out.println(...). The only Problem is that the orders are not shown in the table.
Yes i only create that one instance of the OrderOverviewController class.
And i do nothing with the instance of root. Its just to get the Controller. Actually i don't know why i have to create that instance but i found this way to get a controller here on stackoverflow.

Comment: @James_D yeah, you are right!
That might be the issue!
I added the Output in the constructor of the constructor and its printed out twice.
I will try to fix it and tell you if it worked.

Comment: This was actually @ItachiUchiha's comment above ("Use this instance of the controller...").

Comment: @ItachiUchiha 
I tried this, but the problem i am facing now is that i don't load the view for 
the orderOverViewController. The View is included in a tab in the main view.
I added the code to the post above.
So i do never load it "by hand", but the main view automatically includes it.
At which point in the programm should i try to load the controller now?

Comment: @hiaslosch17 when you have fxml files which contain other fxml components from a different file it's probably best to let them have separate controllers which are instantiated from the main controller. (such that the structure in fxml files and controllers is the same)

Comment: @Jur_ that sounds good, but isnt the controller vor my orders initiated twice then? once by the order view itself, and another time from the main controller? Or is the main controller set up first and then all other controllers from the included fxml files?

Comment: @hiaslosch17 While you could configure the controller in the FXML document, I always load the fxml file from code (Using the FXMLLoader). You can simply add an empty pane with a code ID to the main FXML file to which you set the pane loaded with the sub controller. It's a hierarchical structure, so your sub-controller should only be initiated from the controller/component containing it.

Comment: for example: each tab could contain a pane that is set from code with a separate controller (which has it's own FXML file). Maybe you can even reuse a controller/fxml-file definition if the structure is the same on 2 or more of the tabs. Then if the pane then has it's own custom components the pane controller would instantiate it's own private sub-controllers and so on.